# Android: Singleton class Data gets null when app goes in background

Tags: android, json, garbage-collection, singleton

I am using singleton class in my android app to store the data that is fetch from webserivce.
The problem arrives when, the app goes in background and after few min it come in foreground the application gets Crash because the values stored in singleton class gets null.
I thing the Garbage collection of the phone make the value null.
I had tried this method to solve this issue. But still its coming

```
    private static SingleTon uniqueInstance;

  private SingleTon() {
    }

  public static synchronized SingleTon getInstance() {
    if (uniqueInstance == null) {
      uniqueInstance = new SingleTon();
    }
    return uniqueInstance;
  }
```

Any solution for this problem.

Comment: are you sure you are not forcing a null value somewhere, somehow ?

Comment: Can you post the Exception or the Error ?

Comment: Objects returned by getInstance should not be null, maybe it's your stored instance.

Comment: Yes @Blackbelt i am sure i am not forcing any null value. in the code

Comment: I face this problem when the app is minimized and again maximized after some time.

Comment: Can you post your activity code,where you are using singleton object ?

Comment: multiMap_section_name=SingleTon.getTeacherSectionNameMultiMap();
  multiMap_section_id = SingleTon.getTeacherSectionIdMultiMap();

LIke this way i am calling the data from singlotn class

Comment: Written like this I understand that getTeacherSectionNameMultiMap() is a static method, is it ? Why would you create a Singleton class if you call static methods ? You should do something like this: SingleTon.getInstance().getTeacherSectionNameMultiMap()

Comment: @Gordak yes getTeacherSectionNameMultiMap() is a static method in the singleton class. First time it is working for me. But when i minismize the app. and after restoring the values of the variable in singleton class gets null and the app get crash.

Answer (score 1):

Your application may get killed anytime when it is in background to reclaim some resources. 
If your application gets killed, then all the static variable will automatically be null again. 
If you have some important data to save, save it in a [storage option](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). I suggest you to **always** access you singleton with `SingleTon.getIntance()`. This way, if your instance was killed, you can initialize it.

And don't use static methods in a singleton class... that is just pointless.